# Simplest way to parse the element in this XML C#

Tags: c#, xml

Pretty new at C# so trying to learn xml serialization. I have an xml setup like the following:

```
<Guy>
<Name>
    <Root> 
        <Entry>
            <Favorite> his favorite food is sushi </Favorite>
        </Entry>
    </Root>
</Name>
</Guy>
```

I need to select the "Favorite" tags and return the "his favorite food is sushi". What is the simplest way to go about this in C#? Can XDocument and LINQ extensions be used?

Comment: The simplest way is to put your XML into [this site](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/), and then [deserialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=net-6.0) the XML using the resulting classes.

Comment: _What is the simplest way to go about this in C#?_ The one you either know how to use or that is easiest for you to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
string xml = @"
<Guy>
<Name>
    <Root> 
        <Entry>
            <Favorite> his favorite food is sushi </Favorite>
        </Entry>
    </Root>
</Name>
</Guy>";
        
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
Console.WriteLine(doc.Descendants("Favorite").First().Value);

// or 

foreach(var item in doc.Descendants("Favorite").Select(e => e.Value))
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/Iagop5

Comment: Thanks, doc.Descendants seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach using XPathNavigator:

```
    public static string GetAttribute(string xml, string nodeName) {
      StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
      XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(stringReader);
      XPathNavigator xNav = doc.CreateNavigator();
      XPathNavigator node = xNav.SelectSingleNode("//" + nodeName);
      return node != null ? node.InnerXml : string.Empty;
  }
```

Here's a reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.selectsinglenode?view=net-6.0